# Record of classes that extend single abstract class

Tags: typescript

I'm having difficulty getting the types in a `Record<K, T>` correct for something I'm working on.

I have a base abstract class that a series of other classes all extend. I then have the record where the key is the name of the class, and the value is the class itself. This is so I can do something like `(new componentEditors[type](component)).init()`.

I've tried `Record<string, typeof ComponentEditor>` however that complains that I cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

I then tried `Record<K extends keyof Editors, Editors[K]>` where `Editors` is an interface of the name and types, similar to the `HTMLElementTagNameMap`, however my editor warns me of errors there too:

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'K'.
> TS2538: Type 'K' cannot be used as an index type.

Ideally I would have liked to use something along the lines of `Record<string, ? extends ComponentEditor>` but that doesn't work either.

Below I have a sample of the code I'm working with. Is anyone able to share a working record type?

```js
import ComponentCards from './editors/cards'

export abstract class ComponentEditor {
    protected component: Component

    protected constructor(component: Component) {
        this.component = component
    }

    abstract init(): void
}

const componentEditors: Record<string, typeof ComponentEditor> = {
    ComponentCards,
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyIgFEATASwmygQG8AoBdhfKbCE+EqkjyFS5AFxZhxMhBZsOXHn16DYxSFACu8BgAo1BaeMmHREAJTN5HDhAAWNMADoDImQgC8Q0zOsIAvnI2oBpwiDREdLrmEgBu2DRULIEsKGgYOD7kzClp6CZu5JjAUFQYJAAevERlBUaUtPSMrDYRUZYtNhwA9N0IVNgIkJoAZiNOCACSEADkGEQ8CFAkwMjIAJ4INIZQEMDkfoEpEbxQI3AkCNR0DBid7DOZhRDFpWAzEk-1r2XJcmpESDeZ7XJpgCQAJT4DCoAB4NBEAOYAGgQEHW+BI2BGdTMoIYAD5PMwEL0EAB3OzAWYYeyXRSYxjozEIEYMNF2S6xVaaEgAfj8XzMPzAyL+LBGmiI8BoxC2kReUjxjT0zJIEgRRBRwPqnyVMg6fhoON0avlOuVNygYENXQ4ulI5ItMnx1oA2mqALr6fXkczmJxtCDRQ5-IA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WGPMXw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz I've added a link to the question.

Comment: Please put the code in the question as plaintext; an external link is a great supplement but not sufficient by itself to be a [mre].

Comment: The `ComponentCards` class has a protected constructor so it wouldn't work no matter what, you can't instantiate a protected constructor externally in `initComponentEditor()` ; if I give `ComponentCards` a public constructor then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZGeeW) may work for your needs.  Let me know and I can write up an answer.  If it doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz `new (component: Component) => ComponentEditor` seems to have been what I was missing. Changing the constructor to public in `ComponentEditor` is preferred, so I don't have to overload the constructor in every extending class.

Comment: Could you put the code in the plaintext and make the superclass constructor public yourself so I don't have to talk about that in my answer?